# Login with Facebook always asking password and mail SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swift3, realm, facebook-login

I have a kmm app and when I try to click the FB login button, it will redirect me to the browser, but without the mail or password..
But I do have the fb installed and logged on on my phone.

```
VStack{
   Button(action: {
    loginManager.logIn(permissions: [ .email, .publicProfile ]) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            
            print("ok")

            
        case .failed(let error):
            print("Facebook login failed: \(error)")
        case .cancelled:
            print("The user cancelled the login flow.")
        }
    }
    
  }, label: {
    Text("Facebook login")
      
  })
}
```

How does LoginManager will know that I am already logged in a Facebook app on my iPhone?

I want when the redirect to the web happens that I will already see my account that I am currently logged in my phone. Without having to add my email and password.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the question but Realm remembers the current logged in user. When the app starts, check to see if the App.currentUser property is populated (not nil) and if so, they're logged in already else show the login screen.